Why does my submit button is not functioning properly?
I've been trying to figure out why does my submit button suddenly not working, so I have here a two option to fill up a personal details, the first one is via admin, wherein the admin will create a User and input the `personal details'. The admin side, is working normally.
The main problem I encounter is when User fills up his own personal details, this is where I get a problem, When I submit it, nothing shows, not even returning success or error
The process here, the User register, fill up his personal details, and with the use of auth, I grab it's id and email and include it in the personal details.
Process steps ->
User Register Via Email and Password -> Login Account -> Fills up his personal details -> Using session, grab it's session.user.email and session.user.id and include it on when submitting.
FormPage.tsx (Full Code
const router = useRouter()
    const form = useForm<AccountSchemaType>({
        resolver: zodResolver(AccountSchema),
        defaultValues: {
            first_name: '',
            middle_name: '',
            last_name: '',
            sex: '',
            position: '',
            position_other: '',
            classification: '',

            //DO
            section_or_unit: '',
            division_office: '',

            //Rest
            years_in_service: '',
            undergraduate_course: '',
            date_graduated: '',
            master_degree: '',
            doctorate_degree: '',

            //School
            school: '',
        }
    })
    

    const { mutate, isPending } = useMutation({
        mutationFn: CreateAccountAction,
        onSuccess: (data) => {
            if(data?.success){
                toast({
                    title: "Success",
                    description: data.success,
                    variant: 'default'
                })
            }
            router.refresh()

            if(data?.error){
                toast({
                    title:"Error",
                    description: data.error,
                    variant: "destructive"
                })
            }
        },
        onError: (error: Error) => {
            console.error("Client error:", error)
            toast({
                title: "Error",
                description: "Unable to create a new account. Please try again.",
                variant: "destructive"
            })
        }
    })
    


    const onSubmit = useCallback((values: AccountSchemaType) => {
        mutate(values)
    }, [mutate])


createAccounts.ts
export async function CreateAccountAction(form: AccountSchemaType) {
    // Get the current session
    const session = await auth()

    // Check if user is authenticated
    if (!session || !session.user || !session.user.id) {
        return {error: "You are not authorized"}
    }

    // Additional check to ensure email exists
    if (!session.user.email) {
        return {error: "Email already existing"}
    }

    const parsedBody = AccountSchema.safeParse(form)

    if (!parsedBody.success) {
        return {error: "Something went wrong"}
    }

    const {
        first_name,
        middle_name,
        last_name,
        sex,
        position,
        position_other,
        classification,
        section_or_unit,
        division_office,
        years_in_service,
        undergraduate_course,
        date_graduated,
        doctorate_degree,
        master_degree,
        school
    } = parsedBody.data

    try {
        const newAccount = await db.account.create({
            data: {
                first_name,
                middle_name,
                last_name,
                sex,
                position,
                position_other,
                classification,
                section_or_unit,
                undergraduate_course,
                division_office,
                years_in_service,
                date_graduated,
                master_degree,
                doctorate_degree,
                school,
                // Use non-null assertion since we checked earlier
                email: session.user.email!,
                accountId: session.user.id,
            }
        })

        return {success: "Updated Account", newAccount}

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error creating account:", error)
        throw new Error("Failed to create account")
    }
}

zod-schema.ts
export const AccountSchema = z.object({
    first_name: z.string().min(1, 'First name is required'),
    middle_name: z.string().min(1, 'Middle name is required'),
    last_name: z.string().min(1, 'Last name is required'),
    sex: z.string().min(2, { message: "Select input field" }),
    email: z.string().email(),
    position: z.string().min(1, 'Position is required'),
    position_other: z.string().optional(),
    classification: z.string().min(1, 'Classification is required'),


    //Divsion
    section_or_unit: z.string().optional(),
    division_office: z.string().optional(),


    //Rest
    years_in_service: z.string().min(1, {message: "Select Years"}),
    undergraduate_course: z.string().optional(),
    date_graduated: z.string().optional(),
    doctorate_degree: z.string().optional(),
    master_degree: z.string().optional(),

    //School
    school: z.string().optional(),


});


export type AccountSchemaType = z.infer<typeof AccountSchema>


Schema.Prisma

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String    @unique
  password      String?
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  role          String    @default("teacher") // "DO / school_admin / teacher"
  affiliation   String?
  createdAt     DateTime  @default(now())
  updateAt      DateTime  @updatedAt
  account       Account?
}

model Account {
  id               String  @id @default(cuid())
  first_name       String
  middle_name      String
  last_name        String
  sex              String
  email            String
  position         String
  position_other   String?
  classification   String
  years_in_service String

  section_or_unit      String?
  undergraduate_course String?
  date_graduated       String?
  doctorate_degree     String?
  master_degree        String?

  school          String?
  division_office String?

  account   User   @relation(fields: [accountId], references: [id])
  accountId String @unique

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updateAt  DateTime @default(now())

  @@unique([email])
}


